I can't modify data source views in vs2022
I create Analysis Multidimensional Project In VS2022. I can connect database by Provider is OLE DB Driver for SQL Server but I cant't modify data source views . This is error enter image description here.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.SqlXml.dll' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (Microsoft Visual Studio)
I can see System.Data.SqlXml.dll In C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework. I've tried many ways online but still can't do it. Please help me.
